# What is wrong with my docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Seems like it is a error in my yml file. I read  a lot of articles here but found nothing. I still cannot get it to work. I purposely removed some unnecessary parts of my code, so here it is:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  shop:
    image: azamatibraimov/repository:shop
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - '8080'
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

So,When I do this:

```
docker login && docker-compose up
```

I have this output:

```
ERROR: manifest for azamatibraimov/repository:shop not found
```

Comment: The actual indentation in YAML matters a lot, and can cause the error you show.  Can you edit your question so that the indentation matches what you have locally?

Comment: Show `docker image ls` - does the image you're trying to pull exist?

Comment: Mate, please help me!
The guy who made the tutorial said nothing about creating docker image. So, could you tell my how to create docker image using gradle? 
Or give useful link ,idk...

Answer (score 0):

What or where is the `shop:latest` docker image? Is this something that you are trying to build locally? If so, add the following to your `shop` service:

```
shop:
  build:
    context: .
  image: shop:latest
  …
```

As context, put the folder where the `Dockerfile` for the shop is located.

Comment: Mate, I am following this guy step by step:https://medium.com/@chrischuck35/how-to-create-a-mysql-instance-with-docker-compose-1598f3cc1bee
What should I add to make it work?

Comment: That medium post covers how to set up mysql or postgres, which looks correct in your code too. It is failing with your `shop` service and cannot find the image. Does the image exist in your local registry? Does it have the correct tag? How did you create the image? (How did you come up with the image name and tag?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you pushed the image to a docker hub. `azamatibraimov/repository:shop` Is this the right docker image name?

To pull the image, the correct syntax is:
`username/repositoryname:tagname`

Default tag name is "latest". So, if you left it blank when you pushed image, this could be your correct image name: `azamatibraimov/repository:latest`